# cmake: set not working, values not stored

Tags: cmake

I have this code on a .cmake file (cmake version 3.13.4):

```
# DMF-03 build system - subproject to download and build Boost
# $Id: DownloadBoost.cmake $

cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8...3.13)
project(boost-download NONE)

# If DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX is not set, the build does not happen at compilation time
# DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX is set by ExternalProject
include(ExternalProject)
set_property(DIRECTORY . PROPERTY EP_BASE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ExternalProject")

set(B2_BOOST_TOOLSET "test")
message(STATUS "[DownloadBoost.cmake]: first B2_BOOST_TOOLSET ${B2_BOOST_TOOLSET}")
set(B2_BOOST_TOOLSET "toolset=darwin cxxstd=11")
message(STATUS "[DownloadBoost.cmake]: second B2_BOOST_TOOLSET ${B2_BOOST_TOOLSET}")
```

But set is not working, these are message outputs:

```
-- [DownloadBoost.cmake]: first B2_BOOST_TOOLSET 
-- [DownloadBoost.cmake]: second B2_BOOST_TOOLSET
```

I know message are working because I've several that show values:

```
-- [DownloadBoost.cmake]: first B2_BOOST_TOOLSET 
-- [DownloadBoost.cmake]: second B2_BOOST_TOOLSET 
-- [DownloadBoost.cmake]: UNIX 1 #With value
-- [DownloadBoost.cmake]: WIN32 
-- [DownloadBoost.cmake]: APPLE 
-- [DownloadBoost.cmake]: MINGW 
-- [DownloadBoost.cmake]: MSYS 
-- [DownloadBoost.cmake]: CYGWIN 
-- [DownloadBoost.cmake]: BUILD_SHARED_LIBS 
-- [DownloadBoost.cmake]: CMAKE_C_COMPILER 
-- [DownloadBoost.cmake]: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/c++ #With value
-- [DownloadBoost.cmake]: CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE RELEASE
```

Anyone know what might be happening?

I attach the complete .cmake file:

```
# DMF-03 build system - subproject to download and build Boost
# $Id: DownloadBoost.cmake $

cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8...3.13)
project(boost-download NONE)

# If DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX is not set, the build does not happen at compilation time
# DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX is set by ExternalProject
include(ExternalProject)
set_property(DIRECTORY . PROPERTY EP_BASE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ExternalProject")

### to be removed
set(B2_BOOST_TOOLSET "algo")
message(STATUS "[DownloadBoost.cmake]: first B2_BOOST_TOOLSET ${B2_BOOST_TOOLSET}")
set(B2_BOOST_TOOLSET "toolset=darwin cxxstd=11")
message(STATUS "[DownloadBoost.cmake]: second B2_BOOST_TOOLSET ${B2_BOOST_TOOLSET}")
### to be removed

# Settings that are forced
set (BOOST_FORCED_SETTINGS
    "-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=${BUILD_SHARED_LIBS}" # Match our build
    "-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:PATH=${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}" # Match our build
    "-DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:PATH=${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}" # Match our build
    "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=<INSTALL_DIR>" # This is replaced by ExternalProject
)

# By default, match the Debug/Release of parent project
set (BOOST_DEFAULT_SETTINGS
    "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}"
    CACHE STRING "Options to pass to the Boost CMake configure step"
)

### to be removed
message(STATUS "[DownloadBoost.cmake]: UNIX ${UNIX}")
message(STATUS "[DownloadBoost.cmake]: WIN32 ${WIN32}")
message(STATUS "[DownloadBoost.cmake]: APPLE ${APPLE}")
message(STATUS "[DownloadBoost.cmake]: MINGW ${MINGW}")
message(STATUS "[DownloadBoost.cmake]: MSYS ${MSYS}")
message(STATUS "[DownloadBoost.cmake]: CYGWIN ${CYGWIN}")
message(STATUS "[DownloadBoost.cmake]: BUILD_SHARED_LIBS ${BUILD_SHARED_LIBS}")
message(STATUS "[DownloadBoost.cmake]: CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER}")
message(STATUS "[DownloadBoost.cmake]: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}")
message(STATUS "[DownloadBoost.cmake]: CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}")
message(STATUS "[DownloadBoost.cmake]: BOOST_FORCED_SETTINGS ${BOOST_FORCED_SETTINGS}")
### to be removed

### to be removed
message(STATUS "[DownloadBoost.cmake]: before B2_BOOST_TOOLSET ${B2_BOOST_TOOLSET}")
### to be removed

# set toolset, necessary to work in mac architecture
if(UNIX)
    ### to be removed
    message(STATUS "[DownloadBoost.cmake]: Setting B2_BOOST_TOOLSET value for APPLE")
    ### to be removed
    set (B2_BOOST_TOOLSET "toolset=darwin cxxstd=11")
    set (BOOST_TEST_VARIABLE "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}")
    ### to be removed
    message(STATUS "[DownloadBoost.cmake]: inside B2_BOOST_TOOLSET ${B2_BOOST_TOOLSET}")
    message(STATUS "[DownloadBoost.cmake]: inside BOOST_TEST_VARIABLE ${BOOST_TEST_VARIABLE}")
    ### to be removed
    #first try
    #set(B2_BOOST_TOOLSET "toolset=clang cxxstd=11")
    #second try 
    #set(B2_BOOST_TOOLSET 'toolset=clang cxxflags="-stdlib=libc++" linkflags="-stdlib=libc++"')
    #third try
    #echo "using clang : 11.0 : <cxxflags>-std=c++11 ;" > ./tools/build/src/user-config.jam
endif()

### to be removed
if(UNIX)
    SET(Boost_DEBUG ON)
    # set Boost_COMPILER to mgw13, to avoid (mgw131, detected mgw13, set Boost_COMPILER to override) error with boost_random
    message(STATUS "[DownloadBoost.cmake]: set 'mgw13' value to Boost_COMPILER and BOOST_DETECTED_TOOLSET for Windows")
    set(Boost_COMPILER "mgw13")
    set(BOOST_DETECTED_TOOLSET "mgw13")
endif()
message(STATUS "[DownloadBoost.cmake]: Boost_COMPILER ${Boost_COMPILER}")
message(STATUS "[DownloadBoost.cmake]: BOOST_DETECTED_TOOLSET ${BOOST_DETECTED_TOOLSET}")

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ExternalProject/Install/Boost/lib/cmake/Boost-1.75.0")
message(STATUS "[DownloadBoost.cmake]: CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH}")
### to be removed

# Download and build boost
# Math is required by feasibility tool
ExternalProject_Add(
    Boost
    URL https://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.75.0/boost_1_75_0.zip/download
    UPDATE_COMMAND ""
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=json,math --prefix=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ExternalProject/Install/Boost
    BUILD_COMMAND ./b2 ${B2_BOOST_TOOLSET} --build-type=minimal --with-json --with-math --prefix=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/ExternalProject/Install/Boost install
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE true
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    CMAKE_CACHE_DEFAULT_ARGS ${BOOST_DEFAULT_SETTINGS}
    CMAKE_CACHE_ARGS ${BOOST_FORCED_SETTINGS}
)
```

and the first part of cmake execution traces:

```
[32;1m$ cmake --version[0;m
cmake version 3.13.4

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
[32;1m$ cmake --loglevel=STATUS -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE ../dmf03_6dofsimulator[0;m
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
-- The Fortran compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: /usr/bin/gfortran
-- Check for working Fortran compiler: /usr/bin/gfortran  -- works
-- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info
-- Detecting Fortran compiler ABI info - done
-- Checking whether /usr/bin/gfortran supports Fortran 90
-- Checking whether /usr/bin/gfortran supports Fortran 90 -- yes
-- NCXX4_INCLUDE_DIR => /usr/include
-- NC_INCLUDE_DIR => /usr/include
-- NCXX4_LIBRARY_CXX => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdf_c++4.so
-- NCXX4_LIBRARY_C => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdf.so
-- if => NCXX4_LIBRARY_CXX=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdf_c++4.so - NCXX4_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include - NCXX4_LIBRARY_C=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetcdf.so - NC_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include
-- prefix => _trycompile_netcdf
-- [build_cots.cmake]: UNIX 1
-- [build_cots.cmake]: WIN32 
-- [build_cots.cmake]: APPLE 
-- [build_cots.cmake]: MINGW 
-- [build_cots.cmake]: MSYS 
-- [build_cots.cmake]: CYGWIN 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/googletest-download
Scanning dependencies of target GTest
[ 12%] Creating directories for 'GTest'
[ 25%] Performing download step (git clone) for 'GTest'
Cloning into 'GTest'...
Note: checking out 'release-1.8.1'.

You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
state without impacting any branches by performing another checkout.

If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again. Example:

  git checkout -b <new-branch-name>

HEAD is now at 2fe3bd99 Merge pull request #1433 from dsacre/fix-clang-warnings
[ 37%] No patch step for 'GTest'
[ 50%] Performing update step for 'GTest'
[ 62%] Performing configure step for 'GTest'
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 8.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3.7 (found version "3.7.3") 
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread
-- Check if compiler accepts -pthread - yes
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Build/GTest
[ 75%] Performing build step for 'GTest'
Scanning dependencies of target gtest
[ 12%] Building CXX object googlemock/gtest/CMakeFiles/gtest.dir/src/gtest-all.cc.o
[ 25%] Linking CXX static library libgtest.a
[ 25%] Built target gtest
Scanning dependencies of target gmock
[ 37%] Building CXX object googlemock/CMakeFiles/gmock.dir/src/gmock-all.cc.o
[ 50%] Linking CXX static library libgmock.a
[ 50%] Built target gmock
Scanning dependencies of target gmock_main
[ 62%] Building CXX object googlemock/CMakeFiles/gmock_main.dir/src/gmock_main.cc.o
[ 75%] Linking CXX static library libgmock_main.a
[ 75%] Built target gmock_main
Scanning dependencies of target gtest_main
[ 87%] Building CXX object googlemock/gtest/CMakeFiles/gtest_main.dir/src/gtest_main.cc.o
[100%] Linking CXX static library libgtest_main.a
[100%] Built target gtest_main
[ 87%] Performing install step for 'GTest'
[ 25%] Built target gtest
[ 50%] Built target gmock
[ 75%] Built target gmock_main
[100%] Built target gtest_main
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gmock
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gmock/gmock.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gmock/gmock-generated-matchers.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gmock/gmock-cardinalities.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gmock/gmock-matchers.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gmock/gmock-generated-function-mockers.h.pump
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gmock/gmock-spec-builders.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gmock/gmock-generated-actions.h.pump
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gmock/gmock-generated-matchers.h.pump
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gmock/gmock-actions.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gmock/internal
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gmock/internal/gmock-generated-internal-utils.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gmock/internal/custom
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gmock/internal/custom/gmock-matchers.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gmock/internal/custom/README.md
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gmock/internal/custom/gmock-port.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gmock/internal/custom/gmock-generated-actions.h.pump
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gmock/internal/custom/gmock-generated-actions.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gmock/internal/gmock-generated-internal-utils.h.pump
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gmock/internal/gmock-port.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gmock/internal/gmock-internal-utils.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gmock/gmock-generated-nice-strict.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gmock/gmock-generated-function-mockers.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gmock/gmock-generated-nice-strict.h.pump
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gmock/gmock-generated-actions.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gmock/gmock-more-matchers.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gmock/gmock-more-actions.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/lib/libgmock.a
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/lib/libgmock_main.a
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/lib/pkgconfig/gmock.pc
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/lib/pkgconfig/gmock_main.pc
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/lib/cmake/GTest/GTestTargets.cmake
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/lib/cmake/GTest/GTestTargets-noconfig.cmake
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/lib/cmake/GTest/GTestConfigVersion.cmake
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/lib/cmake/GTest/GTestConfig.cmake
-- Up-to-date: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gtest
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gtest/gtest-death-test.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gtest/gtest.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gtest/gtest-param-test.h.pump
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gtest/gtest-message.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gtest/gtest-typed-test.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gtest/gtest_pred_impl.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gtest/gtest-printers.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gtest/internal
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-tuple.h.pump
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-param-util-generated.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-linked_ptr.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gtest/internal/custom
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gtest/internal/custom/gtest.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gtest/internal/custom/gtest-port.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gtest/internal/custom/README.md
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gtest/internal/custom/gtest-printers.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-string.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-type-util.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-death-test-internal.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-param-util.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-filepath.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-port-arch.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-param-util-generated.h.pump
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-tuple.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gtest/internal/gtest-type-util.h.pump
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gtest/gtest_prod.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gtest/gtest-spi.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gtest/gtest-test-part.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/include/gtest/gtest-param-test.h
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/lib/libgtest.a
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/lib/libgtest_main.a
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/lib/pkgconfig/gtest.pc
-- Installing: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/lib/pkgconfig/gtest_main.pc
[100%] Completed 'GTest'
[100%] Built target GTest
-- Found GTest: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/ExternalProject/Install/GTest/lib/libgtest.a  
-- [DownloadBoost.cmake]: first B2_BOOST_TOOLSET 
-- [DownloadBoost.cmake]: second B2_BOOST_TOOLSET 
-- [DownloadBoost.cmake]: UNIX 1
-- [DownloadBoost.cmake]: WIN32 
-- [DownloadBoost.cmake]: APPLE 
-- [DownloadBoost.cmake]: MINGW 
-- [DownloadBoost.cmake]: MSYS 
-- [DownloadBoost.cmake]: CYGWIN 
-- [DownloadBoost.cmake]: BUILD_SHARED_LIBS 
-- [DownloadBoost.cmake]: CMAKE_C_COMPILER 
-- [DownloadBoost.cmake]: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/c++
-- [DownloadBoost.cmake]: CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE RELEASE
-- [DownloadBoost.cmake]: BOOST_FORCED_SETTINGS 
-- [DownloadBoost.cmake]: before B2_BOOST_TOOLSET 
-- [DownloadBoost.cmake]: Setting B2_BOOST_TOOLSET value for APPLE
-- [DownloadBoost.cmake]: inside B2_BOOST_TOOLSET 
-- [DownloadBoost.cmake]: inside BOOST_TEST_VARIABLE 
-- [DownloadBoost.cmake]: set 'mgw13' value to Boost_COMPILER and BOOST_DETECTED_TOOLSET for Windows
-- [DownloadBoost.cmake]: Boost_COMPILER 
-- [DownloadBoost.cmake]: BOOST_DETECTED_TOOLSET 
-- [DownloadBoost.cmake]: CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /builds/root/drama_gepp/attitude_simulator/boost-download
Scanning dependencies of target Boost
[ 12%] Creating directories for 'Boost'
```

Comment: does it work okay if you just do those set and message commands in a simple CMake project config without all your other stuff?

Comment: Do you configure your project **standalone**? Please, show (add to the question post) **complete output** of CMake when it configures your project.

Comment: Your reported issue cannot be reproduced in a simple example. The way that you set the variables and print them is correct. There should be something wrong somewhere else.

Comment: Offtopic but `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8...3.13)` is probably a bad idea. Some major changes were introduced with CMake 3+ almost 10 years ago. You might as well play roulette to determine your feature set.

Comment: I've attached logs and .cmake file to let you know all information.

Comment: @Friedrich, what do you recommend setting in cmake_minimu_required, given that the cmake version is 3.13.4?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, I'd set the highest version that works for you. Despite the name, it's a mechanism to have backwards compatibility. CMake uses [policies](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-policies.7.html#manual:cmake-policies(7)) for it. What you do is not inherently wrong but covering a decade of CMake development - why?